# Run a function in a loop until

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to loop running a function.
Can't figure it out and here's what I tried:

```
do {
  queryLastCursor(lastCursor).then(lastCursorResults => {
    if (lastCursorResults.hasNext = false) {
      hasNextPage = false;
    }
    console.log(hasNextPage);
  })
} while (hasNextPage);
```

`queryLastCursor` is a method with a call to an API. When it returns the data it would have a value of `hasNext` if it returns false then I'd like to set `hasNextPage` to `false`. The expected behavior would be that it runs the function again and again until we get the result `hasNext = false`. Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: since `queryLastCursor` is asynchronous you'll never update `hasnextPage` since the do/while loop will never allow the asynchronous code to run - change your code

Comment: Why do you have to iterate? Why not just wait for it to return and set it then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do an async process in a loop, I suggest doing it recursively:

```
const runQuery = () => {
  queryLastCursor(lastCursor)
    .then(result => {
      if (result.hasNext) {
        // recursively call itself if hasNext is true 
        runQuery();
      }
    });
}

runQuery();
```

Assuming you'd want to return some data, you can do:

```
const runQuery = async (data) => {
  return queryLastCursor(lastCursor)
    .then(result => {
      if (!data) {
        data = [];
      }

      // assuming you are returning the data on result.data
      data.push(result.data);

      if (result.hasNext) {
        // recursively call itself if hasNext is true 
        return runQuery(data);
      }

      retun data;
    });
}

runQuery() 
  .then(data => {
    // data should be an array of all the data now
  });
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but realistically you need to somehow collect the data returned, so I would maybe consider outlining that, too. Also, calling `runQuery()` would return a promise, realistically you'd need to `await` it or add a `.then` to proceed.

Comment: @9000, that's true. I guess that really depends on how you want to collect the data since the answer would change. I'll post a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer.  Curious (not knocking it just curious) why did you do: data = data.push(result.data), wouldn't it be the same to just do data.push(result.data)?  Or is there a reason why?  @Kousha

Comment: @FabricioG it was a mistake; that's what happens when you code when you are tired ;). Updated the solution. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that:

```
const callApi = async () => {
    let result = await someMagic();
    while (result.hasNext) {
        doSomethingwith(result);
        result = await someMagic();
    }
    return result;
};
const myResult = await callApi();
```

Though this seems risky, what is we always get a hastNext = true ? Some security seems good, like a limit of loops in the while loop.